Trying to use ctypes to emulate keyboard presses but keep getting error code 87
I'm trying to make a python file that I can use to import into other files and use its functionality. It's suppose to use ctypes and sendinput to emulate pressing a key and holding down a key. However, every time I run it, it never does anything, and when I print: ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError I just get error code 87.
I had tried doing this using the keyboard library, then pyautogui, and finally pynput before landing on ctypes because all the other methods weren't accurate enough and when running there were small inconsistencies in the timings. I've never used ctypes or wintypes before so I used ChatGPT for the majority of the code. I've tried doing debugging through ChatGPT's suggestions and scouring the internet, but to no avail. I get no errors when running the code, but when printing GetLastError() it prints "87". Full Code Below
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

# Define constants
INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002

# Virtual Key Code Dictionary
VK_CODE_DICT = {
    'a': 0x41, 'b': 0x42, 'c': 0x43, 'd': 0x44, 'e': 0x45,
    'f': 0x46, 'g': 0x47, 'h': 0x48, 'i': 0x49, 'j': 0x4A,
    'k': 0x4B, 'l': 0x4C, 'm': 0x4D, 'n': 0x4E, 'o': 0x4F,
    'p': 0x50, 'q': 0x51, 'r': 0x52, 's': 0x53, 't': 0x54,
    'u': 0x55, 'v': 0x56, 'w': 0x57, 'x': 0x58, 'y': 0x59,
    'z': 0x5A, ' ': 0x20
}

# Define structures and functions from the Windows API
class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", wintypes.WORD),
                ("wScan", wintypes.WORD),
                ("dwFlags", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", ctypes.c_void_p)] 

class INPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("ki", KEYBDINPUT)]  # Changed to 'ki' to match the API's expected field

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput
GetLastError = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError

def debug_print_input(input_structure):
    """Prints details of the INPUT structure for debugging."""
    print(f"INPUT type: {input_structure.type}")
    print(f"  wVk: {input_structure.ki.wVk}")
    print(f"  wScan: {input_structure.ki.wScan}")
    print(f"  dwFlags: {input_structure.ki.dwFlags}")
    print(f"  time: {input_structure.ki.time}")
    print(f"  dwExtraInfo: {input_structure.ki.dwExtraInfo}")

def print_last_error():
    """Prints the last error from the Windows API."""
    error_code = GetLastError()
    print(f"GetLastError: {error_code} (0x{error_code:X})")

def key_press(char):
    if char in VK_CODE_DICT:
        vk_code = VK_CODE_DICT[char]
        input_structure = INPUT(
            type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
            ki=KEYBDINPUT(
                wVk=vk_code,
                wScan=0,
                dwFlags=0,
                time=0,
                dwExtraInfo=ctypes.c_void_p(0) 
            )
        )
        print(f"Sending key press for '{char}' (VK code: {vk_code})")
        debug_print_input(input_structure)
        result = SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(input_structure), ctypes.sizeof(input_structure))
        if result == 0:
            print("SendInput failed")
            print_last_error()
        else:
            print(f"SendInput result: {result}")

def key_release(char):
    if char in VK_CODE_DICT:
        vk_code = VK_CODE_DICT[char]
        input_structure = INPUT(
            type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
            ki=KEYBDINPUT(
                wVk=vk_code,
                wScan=0,
                dwFlags=KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
                time=0,
                dwExtraInfo=ctypes.c_void_p(0)
            )
        )
        print(f"Sending key release for '{char}' (VK code: {vk_code})")
        debug_print_input(input_structure)
        result = SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(input_structure), ctypes.sizeof(input_structure))
        if result == 0:
            print("SendInput failed")
            print_last_error()
        else:
            print(f"SendInput result: {result}")

# Test case
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time

    # Press and release the 'a' key
    key_press('a')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    key_release('a')
    
    # Press and release the space key
    key_press(' ')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    key_release(' ')

